# how salt can be implemented to prevent pre-computation dictionary attack on password

Tags: security, password-protection, salt

A salt makes every users password hash unique, and adding a salt to a password before hashing to protect against a dictionary attack. But how?

Answer (score 4):

The tool you almost certainly want is called PBKDF2 (Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2). It's widely available, either under the name "pbkdf2" or "RFC 2898". PBKDF2 provides both salting (making two otherwise identical passwords different) and stretching (making it expensive to guess passwords).

Whatever system you are developing for probably has a function available that takes a password, a salt, a number of iterations, and an output size. Given those, it will output some string of bytes. There are several ways to actually make use of this depending on your situation (most notably are you dealing with local authentication or remote authentication?)

Most people are looking for remote authentication, so let's walk through a reasonable way to implement that using a mix of deterministic and random salts. (See further discussion below w/ @SilverlightFox.)

First, the high-level approach:

- Hash on the client against a deterministic salt. The client should never send a bare password to the server. Users reuse their passwords all the time. You don't want to know their actual password. You'd rather never see it.
- Salt randomly and stretch on the server and then compare.

Here's the actual breakdown:

- Choose an app-specific component for your salt. For example, "net.robnapier.mygreatapp" might be my prefix.
- Choose a user-specific component for your salt. The userid is usually ideal here.
- Concatenate them to create your salt. For example, my salt might be "net.robnapier.mygreatapp:suejones@example.org". The actual salt does not matter too much. What matters is that it is at least "mostly" unique across all of your users and across all other sites that might also hash passwords from your users. The scheme I've given achieves that.
- Choose a local number of iterations for PBKDF2. That number is almost certainly 1000. This is too few iterations, but is about all JavaScript can handle reasonably. The more iterations, the more secure the system, but the worse the performance. It's a tension.
- Choose a length for your hash. 32 bytes is generally a good choice.
- Choose a "PRF" if your system allows you to pick one. HMAC-SHA-256 is a good choice.

You now have all the basic pieces in place. Let's compute some hashes.

- On the client, take the password and pass it through PBKDF2 with the above settings. That will give you 32 bytes to send to the server.
- On the server, if this is the account creation, create 8 or 16 bytes of random data as your salt for this account. Save that in the database along with the username. Use that salt, and another set of iterations (usually 10,000 or 100,000 if you're not in Node) and apply PBKDF2 to the data that the user sent. Store that in the database. If you're testing the password, just read the salt from the database and reapply PBKDF2 to validate.

Everywhere I say "PBKDF2" here there are another options, probably the most common of which is scrypt (there is also bcrypt). The other options are technically better than PBKDF2. I don't think anyone would disagree with that. I usually recommend PBKDF2 because it's so ubiquitous and there's nothing really wrong with it. But if you have scrypt available, feel free to use that. The client and server do not have to use the same algorithm (the client can use PBKDF2 and the server can use scrypt if you like).

Comment: It would be much better to use a cryptographically secure, 128 bit number for the salt rather than to rely on app name + user id. For example, if the user sets their password to the same value again, this should result in a unique stored hash. There should be no way to detect that it has been set to the same value by anyone with visibility onto the database.

Comment: @SilverlightFox That approach is useful in local authentication (and I advocate it there) but extremely difficult to deploy in many remote authentication schemes. You can't easily save the salt locally because the user may have multiple devices. So you have to include a salt-fetching challenge/response handshake. That introduces significant complexity to the protocol without significant security benefits (predictable but unique salts do not actually make anything easier on attackers, and the attacker can just request the random salt from the system so it adds no secret).

Comment: Your specific case of "password reuse by the same user on the same system" is an interesting case, and not meaningless (especially given that some users rotate their passwords). But it is difficult as a general rule to justify a significantly more complex protocol, which has its own security quirks. For example: since unauthenticated users must be able to request the salt for any user (in order to authenticate), is is difficult to avoid leaking my list of user accounts to all attackers.

Comment: Agreed. However, the point of a salt is not for it to be secret but for it to make password storage unique even if the same password is used multiple times (either by the same or different users). In the sake of simplicity, I would forgo any client side hashing unless it had a specific purpose (e.g. LastPass where the provider doesn't want to have the decryption key sent to them at all) and do everything server side. There is little benefit IMHO of hashing client side on the web, particularly as you're relying on slow JavaScript, and for most implementations bcrypt on the server is adequate.

Comment: The high advantage of using PBKDF2 on the client is that the client never sends the password to the server in any unhashed form. I consider that very valuable. But I would agree that applying a weak PBKDF2 (1000 iterations, which is about all JS can really handle) with a deterministic salt and then finishing with bcrypt on the server (or even PBKDF2) with a more adequate number against a random salt would be stronger without creating complexity. I'm updating the post now with those thoughts.

Comment: @SilverlightFox please take a look at revisions. input welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What's the md5 hash of "superCommonPassword"? That's easy to pre-calculate.

It's b77755edafab848ffcb9580307e97414

If you steal a password database and see that hash value, you know the password is probably "superCommonPassword".

What's the md5 hash ("aStringYouDontKnowUntilYouStealAPasswordDatabase" + "superCommonPassword")? Oh, you can't calculate that until you steal the database.

An unknown salt means pre-calculating hashes of common passwords is useless. An unknown salt per user means you need to calculate hashes of common passwords for each user. This slows down the attacker and increases his costs.

Don't use md5 for password hashing though. Use bcrypt or scrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: Note that a system wide salt is [known as a pepper](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/41754/8340). This can be considered secret, however user specific salts are implemented on the premise that the salt value isn't necessarily private.