# Trying To Make Sense of RNCryptor

Tags: ios, encryption, rncryptor

I am working on a project and we need to encrypt some user credentials (username, password, userId, ect.) to pass to our server. We have decided to use `AES256` in order to achieve this. Doing some research on this subject it was hard to avoid noticing a project out there, `RNCryptor` that claims to be an easy-to-use solution to this problem.

So I included the framework into my project and soon realized it was not as straight forward as I thought. I was hoping for a solution to where I could encrypt my credential strings by simply - (**1**) derive a key that I would like to encrypt my stringed credentials with, (**2**) pass the key and my string into the appropriate `RNCryptor`'s method, (**3**) retrieve my encrypted string back from said method.

This would be too good to be true however.

The reality of `RNCryptor` is that it has methods like this:

```
[RNEncryptor encryptData:someData 
            withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                password:someString
                   error:&someError];
```

This is confusing because of the terminology.

**WHAT IS PASSWORD?**

This is never explained. A password for what? Is this for a user password I want to encrypt, the password *key* that I want to encrypt with, or the password to login to my computer (*sarcasm*).

**ENCRYPT DATA?**

Is this a UTF8 encoded string of what the user credentials that I want to encrypt? That is my best guess but again, not explained in the `RNCryptor` Github "documentation".

Comment: Zaph's answer is correct, but I'd like to understand your question better. When you say "derive a key," what do you expect to derive it *from*? (RNCryptor derives it from the password you pass.) Encrypting a password is just a specific case of encrypting data; encryption algorithms do not care what you're encrypting. It is difficult to understand the use case here; it feels like what you really want is a key-agreement protocol, not an encryption algorithm. As a note, if at all possible, you should avoid sending the password at all; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31386549/97337 for more.

Comment: You may also find the FAQ at https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor useful. I didn't update the ObjC implementation with this FAQ when I added it to the Swift version; I should probably pull it out into its own thing so that the various implementations can reference a single general FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`password` is used to generate the encryption key, it is an `NSString` the data is encrypted with. `encryptData` is the data to encrypt and is an `NSData`.

Encryption works with data, that an array of 8-bit bytes. You need to convert whatever you have to an `NSData`. For an `NSString` there is the method:

```
NSData *dataToBeEncrypted = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Additionally it requires an encryption key, RNCryptor takes an `NSString` and derives an encryption key from it.

There are of course options and while most of these handles internally by RNCryptor there still some available to the developer using it.

There two main versions with more options, you are probably best off using the password version.

One taking a `NSString` password:

```
+ (NSData *)encryptData:(NSData *)data withSettings:(RNCryptorSettings)settings password:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)error;
```

A second taking an `NSData` encryption key as well as a `NSData` authentication key.

```
+ (NSData *)encryptData:(NSData *)data withSettings:(RNCryptorSettings)settings encryptionKey:(NSData *)encryptionKey HMACKey:(NSData *)HMACKey error:(NSError **)error;
```

> RNCryptor is you best choice, it handles key derivation from a password, a random IV, authentication of the encrypted data and padding.