# AES256 encrypt in Swift3

Tags: encryption, swift3

I had tried to do AES256 encryption in Swift3, by using many libraries like CryptoSwift, but couldnt get proper result.

```
    let aes = try AES(key: anykey, iv: "")
    let ciphertext = try aes.encrypt(data)
```

The mode I want to try is as below.

```
Algorithm:　Rijndael-256
MODE:　 ECB
IV:　NULL
```

if there is mistake in my code, or any better way to AES256 encrypt in Swift3, answer me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) is a useful framework for AES256 encryption and decryption.

```
// Encryption
let data ... // Some data you want to encrypt
let password = "0Bfy8q9475jgjjbsu"
let ciphertext = RNCryptor.encryptData(data, password: password)

// Decryption
do {
    let originalData = try RNCryptor.decryptData(ciphertext, password: password)

} catch let error {
    print("Can not Decrypt With Error: \n\(error)\n")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Comment: Sure thing. It works I have used it before in several projects. Once you get it fired up it is just plug and go. I had some initial troubles in the beginning. See my own question for more information http://stackoverflow.com/q/40685174/3911918

Comment: None of my apps have been rejected that use this.

Comment: @Brandon A thank u for your quick response, one more doubt i have, should i need to do U.S. Export Compliance process to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the CommonCrypto C library which RNCryptor wraps. This comes as standard with XCode. Unfortunately it doesn't have a swift framework setup for it. This project creates a framework for easy use in swift https://github.com/sergejp/CommonCrypto/tree/master/CommonCrypto

You can find example code using the CommonCrypto library here https://github.com/adam-fowler/swift-library/blob/master/data/aes.swift.

Comment: Fixed the link now